# Is it possible to make a copy pattern which includes and excludes files?

Tags: bamboo, bamboo-artifacts

In Bamboos artifact definition I need to make a Copy Pattern which includes and excludes some filetypes. Is it possible to write this type of pattern in Bamboo?

For example I want all files excluding .txt

I need something like this: `**/*, (this shoudl be excluded)**/*.txt` Is negation possible?

I see in the Ant apache docs that this is a way of includng and excluding:

```
<delete dir="${dist}">
    <include name="**/images/*"/>
    <exclude name="**/*.gif"/>
</delete>
```

Am I supposed to paste a similar block into the Copy Pattern field in Bamboo artifact definition?

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade to Bamboo 9.x. Then you can use the `com.atlassian.bamboo.specs.api.builders.plan.artifact.Artifact#exclusionPatterns` field. Unfortunately I can't quote the docs because they're not online yet at https://docs.atlassian.com/bamboo-specs-docs/. However, I do see the field in the https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/atlassian/bamboo/bamboo-specs/9.2.1/bamboo-specs-9.2.1.jar.